# 2D Array Printing as Reference

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have the code similar to below:

```
my @array1 = (); #2d array to be used
my $string1 = "blank1";
my $string2 = "blank2";
my $string3 = "blank3";

my @temp = ($string1, $string2, $string3);
push (@array1, \@temp);
```

The reason I am assigning the strings and then putting them into an array is because they are in a loop and the values get updated in the loop (@array1 is not declared in the loop).

When I run my program, it only gives me a reference to an array rather than an actual 2D array. How can I get it to print out the content as a 2D array and not as a reference or flattened out to a 1D array?

I would like an output like `[[blank1, blank2, blank3],....]` so i can access it like `$array1[i][j]`

Comment: An array can only have scalars for elements; so references to arrays, for example. Elements of those ("second-level") arrays are accessed by dereferncing, so `$array1[0]->[1]` (second element of the array which reference is the first element of the top-level one), or, for convenience simpler syntax is allowed as well, `$array1[0][1]`.  If you want a list of all elements of the second-level array, then derefernce it with `@`, like: `my @sec_lev_ary = @{ $array1[0] };`. So which part of this are you asking about?

Comment: @zdim `derefernce it with @, like: my @sec_lev_ary = @{ $array1[0] };`. this solved my problem. i was having trouble listing all elements of the second level array. thank you!

Comment: Great :)  Then also notice the newer dereferencing syntax, `my @elems = $array1[0]->@*`.  So `->@*` for an arrayref (to get a list of elements),`->%*` for a hashref (etc). This is called [postfix dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax), stable as of v5.24.  A quick search yields for example a [perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature-postfix-dereferencing/) and an [Effective Perler article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array can only have scalars for elements.  Thus this includes references, to arrays for example, what enables us to build complex data structures. See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc), *Tom's Perl Data Structure Cookbook*.

Elements of those ("second-level") arrays are accessed by [dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut#Using-References), so `$array1[0]->[1]` is the second element of the array whose reference is the first element of the top-level array (`@array1`). Or, for convenience, a simpler syntax is allowed as well:  `$array1[0][1]`.

If we want a list of all elements of a second-level array then dereference it with `@`, like:

```
my @l2 = @{ $array1[0] };   # or, using
my @l2 = $array1[0]->@*;    # postfix dereferencing
```

Or, to get just a few elements of the array, but in one scoop -- a [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices)

```
my @l2_slice = @{$array1[0]}[1..2];  # or
my @l2_slice = $array1[0]->@[1..2];  # postfix reference slice
```

what returns the list with the second and third elements of the same second-level array.

The second lines are of a newer syntax called [postfix dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax), stable as of v5.24.  It avails us with the same logic for getting elements as when we drill for a single one, by working left-to-right all the way. So `->@*` to get a list of all elements for an arrayref,`->%*` for a hashref (etc).  See for instance a [perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature-postfix-dereferencing/) and an [*Effective Perler* article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/).

There is a thing to warn about when it comes to multidimensional structures built with references. There are two distinct ways to [create them](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut#Making-References): by using references to existing, named, variables

```
my @a1 = 5 .. 7;
my %h1 = ( a => 1, b => 2 );

my @tla1 = (\@a1, \%h1);
```

or by using anonymous ones, where arrayrefs are constructed by `[]` and hashrefs by `{}`

```
my @tla2 = ( [ 5..7 ], { a => 1, b => 2 } );
```

The difference is important to keep in mind.  In the first case, the references to variables that the array carries can be used to change those variables -- if we change elements of `@tla1` then *we really change the referred variables*

```
$tla1[0][1] = 100;  # now @a1 == 5, 100, 7
```

Also, changing variables with references in `@tla1` is seen via the top-level array as well.

With anonymous arrays and hashes in `@tla` this isn't the case as elements (references) of `@tla` access independent data, which cannot be accessed (and changed) in any other way.

Both of these ways to build complex data structures have their uses.

Comment: your link to "complex data structures" is Tom's Perl Data Structure Cookbook (perldsc). I know you know that, but I like to say the title and perldoc page explicitly whenever I can. :) Say it there times fast: Tom's Perl Data Structure Cookbook, Tom's Perl Data Structure Cookbook, Tom's Perl Data Structure Cookbook!

Comment: @briandfoy Okay, I'll practice :)   You are right I think, and I normally do that (I use perldoc's name since that informs that it is perldoc, so "perldsc" in this case) -- will edit, and I'll go with the full name now, for practice and good measure. I was enchanted by how nicely the link slips into the sentence here.  Good idea to use a name _always_ when it's a generic reference to perldoc.  (For specific needs spelling out the page name may affect the text too much, like with the "dereferencing" link, and a few others.)

Comment: @briandfoy Edited -- but I must complain now, it has no "Tom's" in its name!  (I'm confused, I know it had it and I I've seen it with it recently ... but the perldoc page doesn't have it...?)

Comment: There was a phase there where people were making Perl docs boring and generic, so we've lost a lot of quirkiness and attribute. :(